# if else query that I need to add to restrict users from inputting quantities higher than the stock

Tags: php, mysql

I want to restrict users from inputting quantities higher than the stock.
The quantity of the product is from a different table, the `qty` below is the quantity of the product in the cart.

What would be the best approach to do this?

This is my `add_cart.php`

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
    if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $qty=$_POST['qty'];

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
            echo "Product already on your cart!";
        }
        else{
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cart (userid, productid, qty) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id', '$qty')");
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem/question ?

Comment: add query to restrict users from  inputting quantity higher than the stock

Comment: Quitte simple : get stock value and put condition `if(qty > stock){ //err } else { //Enter }`

Comment: thats what I want to do but the stock quantity is from a different table , also I think my query is wrong

Comment: Query the table that has the info and add it to the logic that @TarangP suggested.

Comment: can you help me from my codes above?

Comment: @Rav Check My Answer

Answer (score 0):

*This is just for demonstration purpose*

```
<?php

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
        echo "Product already on your cart!";
    }
    else{
        //GET STOCK
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from table where stock = '$yourstock' ");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        //CHECK IF QTY IS HIGHER THAN STOCK OR NOT
        if($qty > $row['stock'] ){
            //SHOW ERROR THAT VALUE IS HIGHER THAN STOCK
        }else{
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cart (userid, productid, qty) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id', '$qty')");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('session.php');
if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'];

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from product_stock_table where productid='$id'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) < $qty){
       echo 'out of stock try';
    } else{
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
            echo "Product already on your cart!";
        }
        else{
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cart (userid, productid, qty) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id', '$qty')");
        }
  }
}
```

?>